# MS Access. VBA. How to create a temporary table with 1 record only if it not exist

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am looking for a way to Create a table when Form is opening.
Table should be created just once. So if it exists new one should not be created.
In the same form I would like to save some data from combo boxes in created table.
To do that I tried to use a code:

```
  Sub ViaVBA()
    Const strSQLCreateFoo_c As String = _
          "CREATE TABLE Foo" & _
          "(" & _
          "MyField1 INTEGER," & _
          "MyField2 Text(10)" & _
          ");"
    Const strSQLAppendBs_c As String = _
          "INSERT INTO Foo (MyField1, MyField2) " & _
          "SELECT Bar.MyField1, Bar.MyField2 " & _
          "FROM Bar " & _
          "WHERE Bar.MyField2 Like 'B*';"

    If Not TableExists("foo") Then
        CurrentDb.Execute strSQLCreateFoo_c
    End If
    CurrentDb.Execute strSQLAppendBs_c
End Sub
Private Function TableExists(ByVal name As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    TableExists = LenB(CurrentDb.TableDefs(name).name)
End Function
```

Unfortunately it is not saving selected values from combo boxes.
It seems that the table has no records and it doesn't want to save the values.
When I add at least one record that combo boxes are storing correct values.

How to create a table with one record with some dummy info using the code posted above?

Comment: This is a rather odd requirement. What is purpose of saving values from first record on form to another table?

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate variable input. Delimit parameters for text field with apostrophes. Use VALUES clause instead of SELECT. Use `If Then` instead of WHERE clause to test value of form control. Don't use reserved word Name as variable.

Consider:

```
Sub ViaVBA()
    If Not TableExists("foo") Then
        CurrentDb.Execute "CREATE TABLE Foo(MyField1 INTEGER, MyField2 Text(10));"
    End If
    If Forms!Bar.MyField2 LIKE "B*" Then
        CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Foo (MyField1, MyField2) " & _
            "VALUES(" & Forms!Bar.MyField1 & ", '" & Forms!Bar.MyField2 & "')"
    End If
End Sub

Private Function TableExists(ByVal strName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    TableExists = LenB(CurrentDb.TableDefs(strName).Name)
End Function
```